# Does CCA security require rejection?

Tags: public-key, chosen-ciphertext-attack, kem

It seems like every CCA-secure KEM<sup>1</sup> has some sort of *check* that the decapsulator performs. Sometimes failure will result in rejection ("explicit rejection") or the decapsulator will simply return a random value ("implicit rejection", like in [Fujisaki-Okamoto without aborts](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/604.pdf)). But in any case, the decapsulator knows when a decapsulation fails.

Is this necessary? Is there a CCA-secure KEM where decrypting mauled ciphertexts simply produces pseudorandom plaintexts without the decapsulator being able to detect that it was mauled? This would be a really interesting property for, e.g., PAKEs, where private keys might be low-entropy, and thus passive attacks via decap-and-check-for-error are possible.

It might be that there's a fundamental reason this is impossible. Curious to hear either way.

---

<sup>1</sup> For example, schemes from [LPN](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/401.pdf), from LWE [1](http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/501) & [2](http://eprint.iacr.org/2007/279), from DDH [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%E2%80%93Shoup_cryptosystem) & [2](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/094), from [BDH](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/593), from [codes](https://classic.mceliece.org/mceliece-spec-20221023.pdf), and via transforms like [Naor-Yung](https://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Enaor/PAPERS/cca.pdf), and [Fujisaki-Okamoto](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/604.pdf). These examples are mostly PKE, but they're used for KEMs.

Comment: Are there any additional requirements: like construction being in the standard model or tightness ? Otherwise, RSA-KEM and EIS type KEMs are CCA secure in the ROM (under RSA and Ddh), but there's no apparent rejection in the process.

Comment: Indeed, I think these are good examples of what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say for certain whether "mauled ciphertexts are undetectable" in a KEM -- this is presumably a security property, so one would need a formal security definition and proof (and for the purposes of this security definition, the adversary is the decapsulator, which is a rather strange scenario). But **RSA-KEM** seems to be a counterexample which is CCA-secure but provides no way to detect mauled ciphertexts.

- The keypair is a standard RSA keypair: $pk = (N,e)$ and $sk = (N,d)$ where $ed \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(N)}$.
- To encapsulate under public key $(N,e)$:

  1. Sample $r \gets \mathbb{Z}_N$
  2. The ciphertext is $c = r^e \bmod{N}$
  3. The encapsulated key is $K = H(r)$
- To decrypt $c$, simply output $H(c^d \bmod N)$

The fact that this scheme is CCA-secure (when $H$ is a random oracle) is proven in [Shoup](https://eprint.iacr.org/2001/112.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. It also appears that ECIES-KEM from the same source has this property.

Comment: A follow up, and maybe this should be a separate question: does such an IB-KEM exist? Sepcifically in the face of an adversary who possibly knows the master secret key.

Comment: Follow up: I believe the answer is yes. Section 7.1 of [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2005/058) shows that a KEM version of Boneh-Franklin is CCA-secure. And the ciphertexts are uniformly random, so that satisfies the undetectability requirement.