Post-Quantum secure KEM with CCA security without using PKE
As we know, one of the most common ways to make a post-quantum key encapsulation mechanism (KEM) is as follows:

First, we choose a public key cryptography (PKE) so that it is resistant to chosen plaintext attack (CPA).



Then, using Fujisaki-Okamoto transformation, we obtain an KEM with  chosen ciphertext attack (CCA) security.


Kyber, Frodo and BIKE are samples of the schemes presented in NIST, which introduced KEMs with the CCA security using the mentioned approach (Kyber has CCA2 security).
My Question:
What other methods are there to make a post-quantum KEM
with the CCA security that does not require
the use of PKE in its construction?

My try:
One of the methods is to use the structure presented in NewHope scheme in NIST, but it is noteworthy that in the report NISTIR 8309, it is stated that NewHope cannot achieve category 3 security (page 16, the third paragraph).
More info:
One of the applications of this scheme is in hardware that cannot use PKE because of limited computing power.
Acknowledgment:
@Amin235 thank you for your attention to this question.
Correct the question:
I apologize if I could not express my question correctly and clearly. I am looking for a way to design a post-quantum KEM that does not need to use PKE in its structure. I made the mistake of over-emphasizing the CCA feature.

The question title and summary have some significant differences. In the latter, it's made clear that we talk about post-quantum schemes... In general CCA security doesn't necessarily require FO like transforms there are direct constructions like RSA-KEM or ECIES that achieve CCA security in the random oracle model see here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/107187/does-cca-security-require-rejection/107215#107215

@MarcIlunga Based on your comment, the question was edited.

Apart from focusing on efficiency and established constructions like RSA-KEM, ECIES-KEM, and ElGamal-KEM, etc, there exists an alternative theoretical approach for constructing CCA-KEM. This method leverages Hash Proof Systems (HPS), which provide a framework for building secure encryption schemes.
Hash Proof Systems were first introduced by Cramer and Shoup in their famous work on CCA2-secure public-key encryption (PKE) schemes. These systems are designed to allow efficient verification of whether a given input belongs to a specific set, without revealing any additional information about the input. The application of HPS revolutionized the design of encryption systems, enabling the construction of CCA2-secure PKE schemes with greater efficiency and provable security guarantees.
Building upon this foundation, Wee introduced two novel variants of Hash Proof Systems: "extractable hash proof systems" (XHPS) and "all-but-one extractable hash proof systems" (ABO-XHPS). These variants were specifically designed to enhance security in the context of CCA-secure KEMs. Matsuda and Hanaoka later expanded on Wee’s work, contributing further refinements and improvements to these constructions. Their work explored how XHPS and ABO-XHPS could be used to construct efficient CCA-secure KEMs with stronger security properties and better theoretical foundations

EDIT: Based on the changes made to the question, I've included more information to the answer.
Post-Quantum: Wee gave a construction for ABO-XHPS from XHPS and showed that XHPS can be built from the hardness of factoring. I couldn't find any references for post-quantum XPHS or ABO-XPS, despite the fact that there are many HPS schemes and their variants based on lattices.
PKE Structure: Wee's KEM construction only requires an ABO-XHPS and a target collision-resistant hash function; PKE is not utilized in the KEM.
Key-Agreement/Key-Exchange: The scheme proposed by Wee is a key exchange scheme.

First of all, thank you for answering the question. I have three important questions about your answer and please give clear answers. If possible, I suggest that you add the answers to these three questions to your answer.

First question: Are the KEMs obtained by XHPS and ABO-XHPS post-quantum? (I know Hash-based systems are post-quantum, but I want to make sure. Actually I am looking for a post-quantum KEM)

Second question: Is PKE used in the structure of KEMs that are obtained using XHPS and ABO-XHPS? (The answer to this question is very important to me)

Third question: Are the KEMs obtained using XHPS and ABO-XHPS, key agreement or key exchange? (For example, NewHope is key exchange)

@User0258 I am not sure about the first question, but I feel there should be a lattice-based construction for XHPS. I'll have to look into this further before updating my answer. In response to your second query, the KEM only needs an ABO-XHPS and a target collision-resistant hash function; PKE is not utilized in the KEM. And, the scheme is a key exchange.

@User0258 If the CCA condition is not important, then we can get KEM from HPS, which can be built from lattices. Hence, it is post quantum.

Property CCA is important (one of the important conditions in NIST about KEM), but it seemed to me that I insisted too much on this property, and it led us away from the main point, which is the post-quantum nature of the KEM.

Dear friend, may I ask you once again to edit your answer based on the three questions mentioned in the comments. In particular, specify which of the KEMs are post-quantum and please provide  references.

Based on the edit you made as well as the references linked in your answer, I realized that the output of the KEMs that are obtained using XHPS and ABO-XHPS are only CCA secure and not post-quantum schemes because the difficulty of their problem is hardness of factoring or discrete logarithm. Am I right?

Yes. I cannot guarantee it is post-quantum secure because I couldn't find any post-quantum constructions (mostly lattice-based) for XHPS or ABO-XHPS. Sorry. I assume the reason was because the community was interested in other lattice-based approaches to achieve CCA-KEM.

First of all, thanks again for your interesting answer and please allow me to not accept your good answer as the accepted answer for now and I will wait for other answers so that I can get the complete answer to the question.  Thank you for your cooperation in answering the question.

Your goal appears to be to try and construct a (post-quantum) KEM whose algorithms require significantly less computing power than a PKE scheme. This is fundamentally impossible, because KEMs and PKE schemes are basically equivalent. You know that one can construct a KEM from PKE fairly cheaply, but the converse also holds: hybrid encryption, i.e., the combination of a KEM + a symmetric cipher, yields PKE immediately.
What makes you think, for example, that NewHope is better suited to constrained devices than Kyber? They're pretty much the same.

First of all, thank you for the important points you mentioned. You understand my question perfectly. I am looking for an KEM that does not need to use PKE in its structure. The purpose of designing this special KEM is also systems with limited computing power. As you mentioned in your interesting answer, this is not possible. Now, dear distinguished researcher, I have two important questions and I would be grateful if you could edit your nice answer and in your revision, answer the two questions in detail. Thank you in advance for your cooperation.

Q1: Is there a way to design a post-quantum key exchange or agreement protocols that does not require the use of PKE in its structure? Clearly, in the world of post-quantum cryptography, can we design a protocol as simple as the Diffie-Hellman protocol, so that two parties, without the need for PKE, can reach the shared key?

Q2: Assuming that the answer to the first question is positive and there is a post-quantum protocol with the mentioned feature, then what security features does this protocol have? For example, do they have conditions CCA or FS (forward secrecy)? Did I understand correctly that if we want to design an agreement or key exchange protocol that meets conditions CCA and FS, then we should go to design KEM?

Again, I don't see why you regard Diffie-Hellman key exchange as computationally substantially cheaper than PKE: it costs essentially the same as the ElGamal PKE (which can be constructed in a more or less black-box way from the key exchange).

If what you are asking for in Q1 is a post-quantum counterpart to DH (i.e., a 2-party non-interactive key exchange protocol), we do have a candidate, namely the CSIDH isogeny-based scheme. It can be instantiated in a way that provides forward secrecy and CCA security, but it is computationally much more expensive than say Kyber (although it does have shorter keys and lower communication cost).

Thank you for the good points you mentioned.
